# Java, LibGdx - Checking if there is a Object at x,y on a MapLayer

Tags: java, libgdx

The TiledMapLayer has the function getCell, I am looking for something similar for the MapLayer. Is there a way checking a postion x,y for a object besides from going through every object and calculating the positions ?

Answer (score 0):

Objects already have `x` and `y` properties, but there is no inherent way to get a cell at a certain location. That is because a MapLayer only contains objects, which do not appear in every tile on a map, and can appear at any `(x, y)` coordinate. If you are using Scene2D I recommend turning the map's objects into Actors, especially since objects on a map are not drawn by the MapRenderer, so you have to draw them yourself.